# Derivation: Discerning difference between arithmetic expression with parenthesis versus without using abstract syntax trees

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, arithmetic-expressions

I am trying to illustrate the expression: **( 3 * 4 + 5 * 6 + 7 )** using an abstract syntax tree. I have already illustrated the expression: **( 3 * (4 + 5) * (6 + 7) )**.

[image: exp1]

Could someone please illustrate the expression without parenthesis with order of left-most first. Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
Here is an updated image of what I think may be correct, but please correct me if it is not. Thanks.

[image: xxx]

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: @FelixKling The parenthesis imply desired precedence; but without the parenthesis the operations have equal precedence. What you may be seeking is a question of order. I would like left-most first order; I have updated my question to indicate the order.

Comment: So you are looking for `( 3 * (4 + (5 * (6 + 7))) )`?

Comment: @FelixKling without parenthesis it makes it more confusion to illustrate. My logic is that there is no binary derivation, just a linear path. But I know that this is not correct according to other examples.

Comment: @FelixKling No,  ( 3 * 4 + 5 * 6 + 7 ).